# How to do an inverse log transformation in R?

Tags: r, math, logarithm, inverse

I am familiar with regular log transformations:

```
DF1$RT <- log(DF1$RT)
```

How do I perform an inverse log transformation in R?

Comment: may be: `1/ log(DF1$RT)`

Comment: do you want `exp` (or more generally base^log(x, base=base)`)

Answer (score 39):

The term *inverse* can be used with different meanings.  The meanings are:

1. **reciprocal.**  In the case of [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) (also known as the multiplicative inverse) the inverse of `log(x)` is `1/log(x)`
2. **inverse function**. In the case of an [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) it refers to solving the equation `log(y) = x` for `y` in which case the inverse transformation is `exp(x)` assuming the log is base `e`.  (In general, the solution is `b^x` if the log is of base `b`.  For example, if `log10(y) = x` then the inverse transformation is `10^x`.)